# Input-Output mapping of a static model

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, data-modeling

I am working with computer-vision-based angle measurement system. The Input vs Output data I get is as follows: (input on X axis and output on Y axis)

[image]

The orange line is a 1 to 1 input, output mapping, and the blue crosses are my actual datapoints.

There's wrapping because an angle alpha its the same as alpha+2*k*pi and so on. The data is roughly linear.

Zooming in into the data, I see this:

[image]

Its easy to see that there's a staircaising nonlinearity, a central value where the error is minimal and a linear bias factor.

My question is as follows:
Would it be better to do multiple linear regression models in order to fit this data? or should could it be enough with just one big regression from -45 to +45? What does the theory says about models like this? Is there a python package that can help me with whis problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is the data, and a minimal example to load it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YolNsSiFPfw6jMzxLcwCPsJkoiPjNQum/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ZidTIN6Fd1oVrdr8sYNPIS1NzSRE2_c/view?usp=drive_link

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
angleReal=  np.load("Actual Value.npy")
angleMeas=  np.load("Measurement Value.npy")

plt.figure()
plt.plot(angleReal,angleMeas,"+")
plt.plot(angleReal,angleReal)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: cool question, would require some code to make it reproducible

Comment: I would like to share the data, but I dont really know how. Can we upload .npy files? I'm still a noob in SO

Comment: you can add a google drive link to the file :D